# Contracting experience

Tags: resume, contractors

I have been contracting since 1998 for several different contract companies working power plant and refinery shut downs. The work I do is specialized but I do it for at many different sites for these same contractors every year. How do I list my work experience on a resume without having a redundant amount of pages?

Comment: how about composing a list of sites you worked on under the header of current professional experience with optional description for  each project

Answer (score 1):

List the contractor companies individually, but summarise the sites/projects under the applicable contractor company.